# Open android app with custom url

Tags: android, google-chrome, url-scheme, custom-url

I am trying to open my test app from chrome browser like this.

[image]

Then, from browser, I open like this. 
Webview://

It can't be open unless I use this app. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.naosim.urlschemesender

So, I change to this code and test again. It is not working.

[image]

According to this link, we can't directly open like that for new browser. 
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

So, I follow their url format and open again on my S4. It is not working either.

[image]

May I know how to do? I have attached my project here as well.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/btbazqcltxpw4ee/Webview.zip